MS Excel Keep An Empty Column Between Two Tables
Here's the situation.
I have a single worksheet in which there are multiple tables on the sheet. The main table, named "VALUE", is where most of the data manipulation takes place. There is a second table, named "ValueSummary" to the right - and below -  of the "VALUE" table with a blank column between the two tables.
Here's the problem.
When the "VALUE" table expands (by simply inserting a new column), everything to the immediate right of the table simply moves over to the right. The problem is, is that the "ValueSummary" table does not move (because it's below the VALUE table).
How can I move the ValueSummary table to the right when the VALUE table expands (or left when it contracts)?

How do you go about adding a column? If selecting the whole colum by clicking e.g. B and then right click and choose insert , the table to the right moves.

If possible provide an image of the general structure of where your tables are. If you're expanding a table by simply typing into a cell immediately adjacent to this, nothing should shift. If you're right-clicking and inserting a column things will shift as they normally would. I'm unsure why you'd regularly remove columns, but best practice would be to have them in separate sheets and query the first table and do your summaries within the query so you can right-click refresh and let power query handle the rest. You can load the query below your table and accomplish that way however

Could you please tell how you're using the tables? It shouldn't be a problem if you're using Using structured references with Excel tables - Microsoft Support
